# Show a layout when a ViewGroup is scrolled up

Tags: java, android

I have a ViewGroup with some items. I would like to show a layout in the bottom of the activity once I scroll up that ViewGroup, and hide it otherwise.
The question is: how do I capture the scroll up/down event from a ViewGroup?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [managing touch events in a ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html).

I believe

```
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            if (mIsScrolling) {
                // We're currently scrolling, so yes, intercept the 
                // touch event!
                return true;
            }
        }
```

is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, this ViewGroup is inside a ScrollView? You may override the onOverScrolled of the ScrollView.